# Problem in finding the correct XPath of a scraped page

Tags: python, xpath

I have been trying to learn Python/BeautifulSoup and as an exercise, I want to write a code to check the train ticket prices on a certain route and date. The problem is that I cannot find the XPath of the listings. I have tried many IDs and Classes but it doesn't work. Can you help me out? The website is in Farsi but I guess the prices are obvious, right above the blue buttons.

[URL:](https://www.alibaba.ir/train/RUD-THR?adult=1&child=0&infant=0&isExclusive=false&ticketType=Family&step=results&departing=1398-4-10)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO Danial, you should post some code, so people can see what you have tried, plus what you are trying to do with that code. People will be guessing otherwise.

Comment: Yes, please provide some code or an XPath expression you have tried. Those prices may be obvious in a browser but they are not in the source code of that page.

Comment: I have already tried the following XPaths but it returns nothing:
parser.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-12 available-columns inner-available trans-fade-in train-available-item')]")

//*[@id="available-columns__footer-0"]/div[1]/span[1]/span
<div class="available-columns__overlay"></div>
col-xs-12 available-columns inner-available trans-fade-in train-available-item

Comment: It looks that it is rather tricky to extract data from this site. If you want to view the source of that page from your browser the displayed HTML code differs from that you can see using Web Developer options.

Comment: In addition to the above - I mean what we see in the browser is not exactly the same what BeautifulSoup gets from the Alibaba server.

Comment: is there any way to harvest this data off this webpage? any tricks @JānisŠ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the location strategies to get the price for all the available trains in the page.

**xPath:**

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'available train-availables row')]//div[starts-with(@id,'train-available-item-')]//span[@class='pricing-value']
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**CSS:**

```
div.available.train-availables.row div[id^='train-available-item-'] span.pricing-value
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is working, but the output I get is not the values expected. Here is the code:  
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.alibaba.ir/train/RUD-THR?adult=1&child=0&infant=0&isExclusive=false&ticketType=Family&step=results&departing=1398-4-17")
price = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.available.train-availables.row div[id^='train-available-item-'] span.pricing-value")
driver.quit()
print(price)

and the result: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement

Comment: Seems to be you end-up entering more than 600 chars in comment, can you let me know the exact error message.

Comment: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0fd211f251b34ce5eddc1f41c805f26e", element="5c7e86b5-7544-4491-a6d7-46bdc7e43172")>

Comment: ahhaa I got it. You have to get the `.text` rather the element as part of `price` step.

Comment: this is the line that you need update `price = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.available.train-availables.row div[id^='train-available-item-'] span.pricing-value") .text()`

Comment: My mistake! I forgot to get the attribute! all is ok now :) thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel the issue is resolved.